# Get rotation center of rectangle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

Given the bounding box, relative rotation center, and rotation angle of a rectangle I need to find the absolute rotation center of the rectangle. Here is an image (I wouldn't mind if someone improved it):
[image]
I hope that is clear enough. I need the x and y coordinates of the red dot. I've been working on this for some time now and I am lost with my trivial knowledge of trig. :/

Comment: and what you did so far for same.

Comment: @UmeshA It's kind of a mess. I could tidy it up if you need it.

Comment: Is what you're calling the "relative rotation CENTER" in your question really the "center" in some way, or is it just an arbitrary point?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary point the rectangle rotates around.

Comment: Is rcy = h / 2 and rcx = w / 2?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey No, they could be anything.

Comment: "I am lost with my trivial knowledge of trig" Ha! your name is MathWizz :P

Comment: @Jarrod Heh. I haven't taken trig yet. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the angle of rotation is `a` shown negative above, then the coordinates of the red dot are:

```
rx = x + rcx*COS(a) - rcy*SIN(a)
ry = y - (w-rcx)*SIN(a) + rcy*COS(a)
```

and remember to convert degrees to radians before taking `SIN()` or `COS()`.

Example: `(x,y)=(80,60)`, `(w,h)=(20,60)` and `a=-15°`, with `(rcx,rcy)=(15,30)`

```
rx = 80 + 15*COS(-15°)-30*SIN(-15°)      = 102.25
ry = 60 - (20-15)*SIN(-15°)+30*COS(-15°) = 90.27
```

Here is an output from GeoGebra of the calculation (with negative `y`-axis)

[image: GeoGebra output]

Comment: It works on the x axis, but not the y axis... Gimme a second to check my code.

Comment: It works like to should if `ry = y - (w-rcx)*SIN(a) + rcy*COS(a)` is changed to `ry = y - rcx*SIN(a) + rcy*COS(a)`. Why do you have it like this?

Comment: I was going to the point through point `F` above. From `(x,y)` go down by `w*SIN(a)` to reach point `F`, then by `h*COS(a)` to reach `K` and then up by `rcx*SIN(a)` to reach `I`. Glad to got it working though. The idiotic left hand side coordinate system of 2D graphics always does an number on me.

Comment: Unfortunately it only seemed like it was working. I wasn't playing with the numbers enough. I'll setup a fiddle (jsfiddle.)

Comment: Nice demo. It is not clear really what you want from the title, but the sketched helped tremendously.

Comment: I didn't really know what I wanted when I was asking this question. I was missing a lot of information that surprised me later when testing this. However, this answer DOES answer the question I asked, so I am accepting it.