# How to check if a given nonconvex area completely overlaps given rectangle

Tags: php, javascript, svg, geometry

Is there any well-defined algorithm to check if given *nonconvex* area completely overlaps given rectangle? Both shapes defined by polylines, so we're doing vector geometry. I do not want collision detection, only complete overlapping.

Story is as follows: we have an SVG canvas on which user can put rectangles, possibly rotated. On canvas exists rudimentary layer system (each rectangle is on it's own layer). The request is as this: to delete a rectangle which is completely blocked from sight by other rectangles overlapping it. So, the rectangles other than given rectangle forms non-convex area, possibly also non-continuous.

The target programming language is PHP, but the solution in any language is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out some spatial topology suites (like JTS http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm with various ports)

You can do operations such as union/intersection etc on multiple geometries, in your case, if you union your complex polygon with the rectangle, the result should be the original polygon, otherwise the rectangle is 'peeking' out somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's not subtle but you could check if any point of the object lies within the bounds of the rectangle, if any do then it doesn't cover it completely.

Comment: Problem is, we cannot easily check the inner points of an objects, if we are thinking in vectors. Sure, per-pixel check if the points of given rectangle lie in the same points as the shape over him will work.

Comment: Isn't your object defined by its points?  Or does it have non straight edges?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Sure, objects are defined by points. Basically there are no shapes on our canvas other than rectangles (defined by their corners).

Comment: Do you have to cope with rotation too?  Seems to be coming up a lot lately

Comment: Yeah, all rectangles can be rotated.

Comment: This might be of use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193442/get-rotation-center-of-rectangle

Comment: You would also need to check that no edges intersect.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what happens when rectangles are rotated.. but here's my first, there's a good chance I am way off. Since this was for SVG, I am using javascript. If useful, It should be relatively simple to port it to PHP.

```
(function(win) {
    function Rectangle(el) {
       this.element = el;
       this._area = ''
       Rectangle.instances.push(this);
    }
    Rectangle.instances = [];
    Rectangle.largest = function() {
       var areas = Rectangle.collect('area');
       var largest_area = Math.max.apply(Math, areas); 
       return Rectangle.instances[areas.indexOf(largest_area)]
    }
    Rectangle.collect = function(prop) {
       var props = [], m;
       for (var i=0, l = Rectangle.instances.length; i<l; i++) {
          if (m = Rectangle.instances[i][prop]) {
             var val = (typeof m === 'function') ? m.call(Rectangle.instances[i]) : m;
             props.push(val);
          }      
       }
       return props;
    }
    Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
       if (!this._area) { this._area = this.element.width * this.element.height; }
       return this._area;
    }

    Rectangle.prototype.overlaps = function(r) {
       var origin_inside = r.element.x <= this.element.x && r.element.y <= this.element.y,
           ends_inside_x = r.element.x + r.element.width >= this.element.x + this.element.width,
           ends_inside_y = r.element.y + r.element.height >= this.element.y + this.element.height;

       return origin_inside && ends_inside_x && ends_inside_y

    }




  rect1 = new Rectangle({width:10, height: 20, x:10, y:30});
  rect2 = new Rectangle({width:5, height: 30, x:20, y:40});
  rect3 = new Rectangle({width:5, height: 1, x:12, y:31});


  console.log(rect2.overlaps(rect1)) //false
  console.log(Rectangle.largest().overlaps(rect2)) //false
  console.log(rect2.overlaps(rect2)) //true
  console.log(rect3.overlaps(rect1)) //true

   //to use this with actual SVG elements, 

   var svgCanvas = document.getElementById('svgElementId');
   var ctx = svgCanvas.contentDocument

   svgr1 = new Rectangle(ctx.getElementById('rect1'))
   svgr2 = new Rectangle(ctx.getElementById('rect2'))

   console.log(svgr1.overlaps(svgr2)) //true

})(this);
```

Comment: ok, found the solution for rotation. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect).in which case the 'overlaps' method and the 'area' method should use this.  It returns an object which has 'left', 'top', 'width' and 'height' properties. eg. r.element.getBoundingClientRect().left Might be worthwhile to write a wrapper method for this